# Monotonically increasing $f$ .

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f$ be a monotonically incresing function from $[0, 1]$ into $[0,
>  1]$. Which of the following statements is/are true?
>
> $(1)$ $f$ must be continuous at all but finitely many points in $[0, 1]$
>
> $(2)$ $f$ must be continuos at all but contably many points in $[0, 1]$
>
> $(3)$ $f$ must be Riemann integrable
>
> $(4)$ $f$ must be Lebesgue integrable

I can prove that $(3)$ is true.. and so, $(4)$ is also true. But for the remaining cases?

Comment: $0$ discontinuities is a both both finite and countable number... So that is not a counterexample to $1$ and $2$.

Comment: ya.. you are right..@Johanna

Comment: i have edited my question.@Johanna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can firstly consider the function:
$$f(x)=2^{\lceil \log_2(x)\rceil}$$
which has a discontinuity at every power of $2$ in the interval. This provides a counterexample to $1$.

For $2$, notice that we can sum the lengths of the discontinuities; to be quite formal, notice that wherever $f$ is discontinuous, there is a half-open interval missing from the image $f([0,1])$. The measure of these missing half-open intervals cannot exceed $1$, and every discontinuity must contribute an interval of positive measure to $[0,1]\setminus f([0,1])$. Think about why we can't have uncountably many intervals of positive measure while having their union have finite measure.

Comment: nice explanation..thank you ...@meelo

Answer (score 5):

The second case is true. The reason is that for a monotone increasing function, a discontinuity can only be a jump discontinuity, which means that it removes an interval from the range. The deleted intervals are disjoint because of the monotonicity. Because there are countably many rationals, there can only be countably many such intervals deleted.

But the first case is false, in that there can be countably infinitely many discontinuities. For example, you could have a function which is $1-1/n$ on $[1-1/n,1-1/(n+1))$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ and $1$ at $1$.

Comment: Your counter example doesnot capture the hypothesis.

Comment: @MessiLio You mean the monotonically increasing hypothesis? Usually I assume increasing really means nondecreasing unless the word strictly is used. In any case it is easy to see how to change this if that bothers you, just replace $n$ with $x/2+n$ or something. (The accepted answer has the same "problem" by the way but I notice you didn't write the same comment there for some reason...also either way this question has had an accepted answer for almost 8 years now.)

Comment: No, about the range. I think, we can take $1-1/n$ instead of $n$ for the functional value. Further, I feel your answer is nice and humble.

Comment: Oh, I missed the $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]$ bit all along, thanks.